# After update to 12.04 LTS 64bit I got an update that I cannot install: "Multi-arch versions of former ia32-libraries"

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

Since I updated my system, this update is shown, but cannot be selected. I guess, because it does not fit to my 64bit system.

But: since it is there, I always got the information that update(s) are available - which is really not the case.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Synaptic Package Manager.
2. Second: Search for `ia32-libs-multiarch`.
3. Right click and mark for upgrade then apply. (If you see something about Fluendo your problem will be resolved after this finishes.)

If that doesn't work, [try this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11887928).